# How to parse a variable in while loop multiple times

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, while-loop, environment-variables

Here is my shell script and where 'i' stands for key.txt. Key file consists of around 8 properties and its values separated by a space like shown below.

Key.txt file :

```
bat slservice
solr slservice
tvs kimservice
ACM kimservice
product kimservice
tax kimservice
tvs kimservice
SNB taxservice
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read i
do
    key=$(echo $i | awk '{print $1}')
    service=`echo $i | awk  '{print $2}'`
    ip=`cat IP.txt | grep $service | awk '{print $2}'|awk 'NR==1{print $1}'`

    echo "VALIDATING $service properties"
    echo "validating $key in $service IP = $ip"

    curl -X GET -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" http://${ip}/v1/config 2>/dev/null>$service.json

    v1_value=$(jq ".\"$key\"" "$service.json" | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b")

    echo "$key $v1_value" > file.txt

    acutal_value=$(cat file.txt | grep "$key" | awk '{print $2}')
    LB_name=$(cat mapping.txt | grep "$key" | awk '{print $2}')
    LB_ip=$(cat LB.txt | grep "${LB_name}" | awk '{print $2}')

    if [ "${acutal_value}" == "${LB_ip}" ]; then
        echo "$key of $service value is matching $v1_value = $LB_ip"
    else
        echo "$key of $service v1/value ${acutal_value} is notmatching to GCP LB ${LB_ip}" 
    fi

done < key.txt
```

The above script is working fine and giving the exact output if we use mapping.txt file alone as a input file for LB_name variable.

But in my current situation I have 4 mapping (mapping1.txt to mapping4.txt)files and each mapping file should run only once for execution of all the props in key file and then followed by 2,3,4 files.

Here is the exact line that we are talking about:

```
 LB_name=$(cat mapping.txt | grep "$key" | awk '{print $2}')
```

Waiting for suggestions !

Comment: Note sure what you are looking for here...  Why don't you loop on the mapping files?  Ex: `for i in 1 2 3 4; do LB_name=$(cat mapping$i.txt | grep "$key" | awk '{print $2}'); done`

Comment: `for i in 1 2 3 4; do LB_name=$(cat mapping$i.txt | grep "$key" | awk '{print $2}'); done`
If we add above loop inside the while loop then it will be changing continuously for every prop that is there in key.txt

Comment: The idea is to loop, set it up in your code so it does what you want.  I was suggesting a way to do it, not a full solution (I would have put it as an answer had I done that).